# Remove click after going to another scene in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

After switching to my 2nd scene, the keyboard event does not work until I left-click the screen.
How to avoid that left click so that I can trigger my keyboard event directly right after moving to my 2nd scene?

More details you may need:

**1st Scene**

```
btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, initGame);

function initGame(e:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Gameplay");
}
```

**2nd Scene**
I only use 1 frame. I have an object. I set keyboard event function to move the object to right or left. I `stop()` the frame.
My keyboard function doesn't work until I give the screen a mouse click.

```
var moveUp:Boolean = false;
var moveDown:Boolean = false;
var moveLeft:Boolean = false;
var moveRight:Boolean = false;
var isMoving:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveCowboy);
function moveCowboy(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.W) {
        moveUp = true;
        if (isMoving == false)
            mycowboy.gotoAndPlay(15);
        isMoving = true;
    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.S) {
        moveDown = true;
            if (isMoving == false)
            mycowboy.gotoAndPlay(15);
        isMoving = true;
    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
        moveLeft = true;
        if (isMoving == false)
            mycowboy.gotoAndPlay(15);
        isMoving = true;
    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
        moveRight = true;
        if (isMoving == false)
            mycowboy.gotoAndPlay(15);
        isMoving = true;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stopCowboy);
function stopCowboy(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.W) {
        moveUp = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.S) {
        moveDown = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
        moveLeft = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
        moveRight = false;
    }
    if (moveUp == false && moveDown == false && moveLeft == false && moveRight == false) {
        if (isMoving == true)
            mycowboy.gotoAndPlay(1);
        isMoving = false;
    }
}

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(20);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, myTimerFunc);

function myTimerFunc(e:Event):void {
    //cowboy movement
    if (moveUp) {
        mycowboy.y -= 3;
        mycowboy.rotation = 0;
    }
    else if (moveDown) {
        mycowboy.y += 3;
        mycowboy.rotation = 180;
    }
    else if (moveLeft) {
        mycowboy.x -= 3;
        mycowboy.rotation = -90;
    }
    else if (moveRight) {
        mycowboy.x += 3;
        mycowboy.rotation = 90;
    }
}

myTimer.start();

stop();
```

Comment: Post all the related code, not just some description of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this at the end of your code

```
stage.focus = stage;
```